# MYSQL get rows not axisting in other table

Tags: mysql, select, exists

I have two tables with 1 identical data column for comparison.

One table "species" is a wide list of species and each data row has one unique id called "suid" add. to its primary id as usual.
The second table "printpipe" is a shopping cart for printouts and each
row has the suid from the species and a unique personal id from the user "guid".

Now I want to get all rows from "species" having empty field "stockimg" and not "noimage.png" in field "stockimg" AND do not exist in table "printpipe" with same suid AND having memb_guid identical to users guid I have as variable $guid

My query I tried is:

```
$get_allspecies = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM  species WHERE stockimg <> 'noimage.png' AND stockimg <> '' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM printpipe WHERE printpipe.suid = species.suid AND memb_guid = '$guid') ORDER BY name_sc, name_de");
```

But it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I forgot to tell that it is to list all data sets not being already in shopping cart

Comment: Please consider  following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply.
I further investigated more in this yesterday and got this solution:

SELECT * FROM species WHERE
stockimg <> 'noimage.png'
AND stockimg <> ''
AND suid NOT IN
(SELECT suid FROM printpipe WHERE memb_guid = '$guid')
ORDER BY name_sc, name_de

this worked for me.
"noimage.png" is an image file showing a dummy image in case
no corresponding image has already been uploaded.
To be sure also empty fields are handled i have also exclaimed them.
So only fields with images are taken.
And they needed to be compared with the other table printpipe where
suid is also used and so can be compared.
So now if the user has the species already in his printpipe (cart)
the species is not shown in the other list (catalogue) anymore to be chosen for
the shopping cart for prints[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should use `LEFT JOIN` for this which will take all the records from the table of the left hand side of the `JOIN`. Then you can use a `WHERE` clause to filter out anything but the `species` not in `printpipe`. It'll make the code a lot simpler, like so:

```
SELECT S.*
FROM species S
LEFT JOIN printpipe P
    ON S.suid = P.suid
WHERE 
    S.memb_guid = '$guid' -- Member GUID
    AND S.stockimg <> '' -- Not empty
    AND S.stockimg <> 'noimage.png' -- Not noimage.png
    AND P.suid IS NULL -- Doesn't exist in printpipe
ORDER BY S.name_sc, S.name_de
```

This assumes the `memb_guid` field is part of the `species` table
(otherwise if it's part of the `printpipe` table it's not possible to get records that don't exist in `printpipe` for a specific value in `printpipe`).

Also your post says "*having empty field "stockimg"*" but your query does *not empty field stockimg*. I assumed your post had a typo and you really meant *not empty*.

Note for anyone who cares about security in addition to the logical and syntactical answer to this question, using inline variables as part of a SQL string (such as in OP's example) are susceptible to SQL injections. There are alternative ways to leverage variables as part of the query instead.

Comment: this is insecure as it i s vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @nbk No it's not because it is just a raw query. If OP uses it in such a way that is insecure, sure that's possible, but that's outside the context of my answer. You're welcome to comment on OP's original post which may be an insecure way of running a SQL query, but you shouldn't downvote my answer which isn't the same as OP's usage of his query.

Comment: every unsecure Answer will be downvoted, as the insecurity is not mentioned or corrected

Comment: @nbk Sorry but that just doesn't make sense, you are incorrect. It's only insecure if used in an insecure way, it is not insecure as a query in itself, such as if it was manually ran in MySQL Workbench. One could argue any query is insecure and be downvoted based on the loose criteria you're using. Not to mention, **SQL injection** vulnerabilities is irrelevant to OP's question, but you certainly can inform OP on better practices as a sidenote, as I mentioned.

Comment: No, sql injection comes mostly because inexperienced user copy code from high rep users, so it is their duty to help to prevent this.

Comment: @nbk I don't disagree with helping new users understand SQL injections (and subsequently I updated my answer with a footnote on it, since OP's query could be at risk for one). But again my query in of itself is not at risk for one since it is **not** a string of SQL code. It is just a raw query that stands alone. One would need to use it in a string improperly to **then** put themselves at risk. Downvoting the answer doesn't explain to new users why, and could be confusing when the answer itself is correct both logically and syntactically. Commenting instead on the OP is probably most helpful.